# PDF url validation in chrome headless browser fails - protractor typescript f\w

Tags: typescript, automation, protractor, google-chrome-headless

I am trying to automate validation of a pdf url that is opened in a new tab is as the expected(url). It is an angular application and we use protractor-typescript framework.

Steps followed in this is as below:

1.Click on a pdf link

2.Pdf opens in a new tab in the same browser window

3.Get all the window handles 

4.Check if the window handles count >1 

5.Switch to the new tab using the last window handle

6.Get the current browser url

7.Check if it is the expected url

it is an angular application, pdf is non-angular

```
public async waitForWindowHandle() {

    browser.driver.wait(function () {
        return browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(function (handles) {
            if (handles.length > 1) {
                return true;
            }
        });
    }, 20000, 'Waited for window count to be greater than 1');
}


await browser.sleep(1000);
browser.ignoreSynchronization = true
wrapmeth.waitForWindowHandle();
browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(async function (handles) {
    expect(2, "pdf did not open in new Tab").to.equal(handles.length);
    browser.switchTo().window(handles[1]).then(async function () {
        currentUrl = await browser.getCurrentUrl();
    });
});
```

Automation works fine in chrome browser, but promise is timed out in chrome headless mode. It doesn’t proceed after step4. We are not able to get the pdf url from the new tab. Any non-pdf url works fine. Please let me know if has anyone faced such an issue before and resolved it. Any inputs on this would be helpful. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to use it:

   `export async function countTabs () {
     const allTabs = await browser.getAllWindowHandles();
     const allTabsLength = allTabs.length;
     console.log('===my tabs count is --->> ' + await allTabsLength);
     return allTabsLength;
   }`
2. Use await/async to resolve the promises

Comment: I am able to get the windowhandle count. Not able to get the pdf url that is opened in the new tab